# where is information about virtual directories stored?

Tags: iis, settings, virtual-directory, port

Server hosted somewhere on internet just broke down, so guys from IT support decided to install Linux temporarily so we can access file system in order to do backup. We have there some web services installed as virtual directories, and, of course, we don't have documented anything regarding their ports, etc...

Where can I find that information without using any applications?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire IIS configuration for IIS6 is in c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\metabase.xml.  Just search for your site name and you should jump to the web section (move past the FTP section if you stop there first).  Get the ID from the path and then keep searching by {id}\ until you find the virtual directory details.

In IIS7 it's in c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config as long as shared configuration isn't enabled.  You can confirm that by looking in c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\redirection.config.